# Como ler um PDF contendo caracteres acentuados usando iText?

Tags: java, itext

Estou tentando ler um PDF usando essa biblioteca iText, porém, caracteres acentuados são ignorados, já olhei a Codificação do projeto e esta como `UTF-8`.

```
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader("arquivo.pdf");
String conteudo = PdfTextExtractor.getTextFromPage(reader,1);
System.out.println(conteudo);
```

Exemplo:

- Texto no PDF: `Exercícios`
- Saída: `Exerc cios`

Comment: Estranho cara, fiz um exemplo aqui lendo pelo `filename` também, com o projeto e todos os recursos dele como `UTF-8` e estão ok. Faça um teste passando o `InputStream` do seu arquivo e não o `filename` e veja se está OK. Se estiver errado, tente forçar o `InputStream` como `UTF-8`

Comment: Eu não entendo de `iText`. É apenas uma teoria, mas você importou alguma fonte padrão (que suporte acentos)?

Comment: Deu certo Bruno, nao sei por qual motivo o arquivo pdf q eu estava testando estava dando esse problema. testei com outro e funcionou perfeitamente! Obrigado

Answer (score 0):

Talvez o pdf não estivesse usando uma fonte existente no Windows. Recentemente tive um problema na abertura de um PDF que usava uma fonte que não exisita no Windows. Após a instalação da fonte e registro do diretório de fontes do Windows o problema foi resolvido.

```
FontProgramFactory.RegisterSystemFontDirectories()
```

Obs.: A solução acima foi utilizando o Itext7